# can the qgis tool connect to AWS athena?

Tags: database, amazon-athena, qgis

I am looking for an alternative to postgis installed on an RDS and I want to explore the option of using AWS athena, but I don't know if the Qgis tool can connect, if so, what kind of database do I have to configure in Qgis?

Comment: I think it looks like a postgis database to QGIS but I've never actually tested it